# Preventing authorized users from accessing an action

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I know if I have a method and I only want `Authenticated` uses to use it I can mark it with:

```
[Authorize]
```

If I have a method where I want both `authorized` and `non authorized` people to use it I can mark a method with:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
```

If I have a method where only `Anonymous users` can use and `not Authenticated users` how can I do this?

Comment: What do you want to do when the authenticated user tries to access that method?

Comment: There would never be a need for that, as an authenticated user can trivially turn themselves into an anonymous user, so it would be trivial to "fool" the authorisation check.

Comment: @RB, Login pages are good examples for that need.

Comment: @haim770 Happy with just going to the standard error page

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `UnAuthenticatedOnlyAttribute`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class UnAuthenticatedOnlyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string RedirectTo { get; set; } = "/Error";

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User;

        if (user != null && user.Identity != null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(RedirectTo);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[UnAuthenticatedOnly(RedirectTo = "/Main")]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    // ...
}
```